# Non-blocking data transfer between device and host in ArrayFire

Tags: parallel-processing, gpu, arrayfire

Is it possible to use non-blocking data transfer between host and device in ArrayFire?
Indeed, because of some issues, I want to keep parts of my code in naive C++. So, I want to hide part of the computation behind the data transfer required in the code.